# migrate windows phone 7.1 to windows phone 8 error

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, expression-blend

I'm trying to migrate my application from windows phone 7.1 to windows phone 8.
I have this error:

```
Error   1   Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=3.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event. D:\project\WP8\Vp.Front.WinPhone7-mango\Vp.Front.WP7Mango\Auth\LoginPage.xaml   1   1   Vp.Front.WP7Mango
```

[image]
 How can I resolve this:

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the dll and re-add from the 8.0 directory.
 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Windows Phone\v8.0\Libraries\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll`